# Icefaces: Disable validations with checkbox or similar

Tags: validation, icefaces

I want to disable the required attribute of the inputText, or any other validator, depending on the value of the selectBooleanCheckBox when I click on the Save Button, How I can do it?

I tried this, but with not result.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with letting the value of the checkbox controll the required attribute of the inputText. With partialSubmit="true" on selectBooleanCheckbox you can trigger the required value also if you want to validate the inputText value when losing the focus on inputText.

For Example:

*view.xhtml*

```
<ice:inputText required="#{mybean.inputRequired}" .../>
<ice:selectBooleanCheckbox 
    value="#{mybean.inputRequired}"
    partialSubmit="true".../>
```

*MyBean.java*

```
public class MyBean {
    private boolean inputRequired;

    public boolean isInputRequired() {
        return inputRequired;
    }

    // setter and other stuff
}
```

myBean has to have at least extended request scope.